# Add one OpenGL object like QOpenGLWidget in QgsMapCanvas in a correct lat and lon

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, c++, qt

I want to add a large number of points to a `QgsMapCanvas` in a way that updates them every **100 milliseconds.** In my initial attempt, I used `QgsMapCanvasItem` and `QPainter` to draw these points on the map. While it technically works, I've encountered lag in loading map , excessive CPU usage, and overall poor performance.

My goal is to improve the performance of this operation, and I've considered using **OpenGL** for this purpose. However, I'm struggling to correctly position the points on the map, especially when the user **drags and drops the map**.

I have one `OpenGLItem` class like this:

```
class OpenGLItem: public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
public:
    OpenGLItem(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    void  setCenterPoint(QPointF &centerPoint);

protected:
    void        initializeGL() override;

    void        resizeGL(int w, int h) override;

// I draw my Points in this function

    void        paintGL() override;

private:
    QPointF  centerPoint;
};
```

and I add it to map like this:

```
OpenGLItem *openGLWidget   = new OpenGLItem;
auto        mapCoordinates = QgsPoint(33.0, 31.877);
QgsPointXY  mapPoint       = mapCanvas->getCoordinateTransform()->transform(mapCoordinates);

// This part makes my position become wrong
// becouse widget should move and move dont accept QPointF
QPoint  pixelPoint(abs(static_cast<int>(mapPoint.x())), abs(static_cast<int>(mapPoint.y())));

openGLWidget->move(pixelPoint);
mapCanvas->scene()->addWidget(openGLWidget);
```

If I add any widget in mapCanvas by using `addWidget` function Its position will change by drag and drop!

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you mean your widget is draggable while it should not or that it does not stay at the correct geographical location when the user interacts with the map canvas?

Comment: @bugmenot123 yes Exactly.

Comment: *Both* of the things I said?

Comment: @bugmenot123 `move` function accepts QPoint which means `int` but converted point is `QPointF` which is `double` so this makes a wrong position.
on the other hand by using `addWidget` function and adding widget in map , makes it move while I drag and drop the map and its lon and lat will change.
I didnt want widget will be draggable I want to add  `QOpenGLWidget` instead of `QgsMapCanvasItem` but it acts like `QgsMapCanvasItem`.
I want to use `GPU` to draw my points instead of `QPainter` which use `CPU`.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.